# std::thread not showing result of std::cout

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-code, c++17

I'm learning C++ multithreading and below is a piece of code I wrote. I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.67.2. The goal is to spawn a thread and conduct a fizzbuzz game using the name of the player given:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int nplayers{4};
const int max_number{30};
string player_names[] = {"Abdul", "Bart", "Claudia", "Divya"};

void speak() {
    for (int n = 1; n <= max_number; ++n) {
        string player = player_names[(n-1)%nplayers];
        
        cout << player << " says ";
    
        if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0) {
            cout << "fizzbuzz!";
        }
        else if (n % 3 == 0) {
            cout << "fizz!";
        }
        else if (n % 5 == 0) {
            cout << "buzz!";
        }
        else {
            cout << n;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // speak();
    thread game{speak};
    game.join();
}
```

The desire output is:

```
Abdul says 1
Bart says 2
Claudia says fizz!
Divya says 4
```

But instead, the there's nothing shown in the output as shown in the following image:
[output from visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2K4o.png)
I'm using the g++ compiler in linux bash terminal native to visual studio code to compile the code. There are no errors in the compilation, but after I exectue the code, there's nothing showing.

Could anyone help me to catch the bug or identify the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: [Code works just fine in regular old GCC when passed `-pthread`](https://tio.run/##jVJdb4MgFH3nV9yxtLHpurbp9qQ22ce/WJoGER2bohFoVo1/fQ4lWrs063i5l3PPORwCNM8XMaVNc8sFTXTIwOOZVAUj6RadMPVukHCMGA4X8RYhLU0FQVImc0IZSBW6CNFMSAVcKBB5Qo6skNVD7Y7glHzthU4DVlSblZlYP7DkfWf3tgMfKvwUhDrBd4CfSaHa@pIQHXLStq/8cCTYyNEh4yHInJFPZwYVArOirACni2B81q4pnj8614X5XPTcdp1FMJKzLI5YrGeT/jI7d1ANDc20As/r9abDIMlRArbkgcgjcARMYAO@DyuYTqHdPXa7cZ6xKY54WQa6LG/w6eh66Fgi2S/fP53@4XIlz5Usl1XiEr8fMhEmdl6jGiH7SbgYnnO57N/XsuyfhNg8T9UNaou3wP1H1ipdVDfNN40SEstmkVvFDw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online"). Have you tried running the binary in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: One of the key takeaways from fizz buzz is that you don't have to explicitly check for fizzbuzz. If you structure your code correctly, it will print automatically when it's supposed to.

Comment: Code works fine here, on Linux. There's nothing obviously wrong with the shown code.